# Confused about behaviour of base class

Tags: python

This follows a question I asked a few hours ago.

I have this code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print 'A called.'
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, a):
        print 'B called.'

x = B(1, 2)
print x.a
```

This gives the error: `AttributeError: 'B' object has no attribute 'a'`, as expected.  I can fix this by calling `super(B, self).__init__(a)`.

However, I have this code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        print 'A called.'
        self.a = a

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, a):
        print 'B called.'
        print a

x = B(1, 2)
```

Whose output is:

```
B called.
2
```

Why does this work? And more importantly, how does it work when I have not initialized the base class? Also, notice that it does not call the initializer of `A`. Is it because when I do a:

`def __init__(self, b, a)`

I am declaring `b` to be an attribute of `B`? If yes, how can I check `b` is an attribute of which class - the subclass or the superclass?

Answer (score 4):

The way you defined it `B` does not have any attributes. When you do `print a` the `a` refers to the local variable `a` in the `__init__` method, not to any attribute.

If you replace `print a` with `print self.a` you will get the same error message as before.

Comment: Am I right in calling `b` an attribute of the class or is there some other Pythonic term for it?

Comment: Uhm, most importantly, what is the difference between 'instance variable' and 'instance attribute'?

Comment: @Jeremy: `__init__` is just a function, like any other. `b` is just an argument of that function. Nowhere is `b` set to be an attribute of anything. It's only when you do e.g. `self.a = a` that you define an instance attribute (aka instance variable).

Answer (score 2):

In your second code, calling `print a` works because you are printing the variable passed as a parameter to B's `__init__` function, not the `self.a` variable (which is not initialized because `A.__init__` was not called). Once you leave the scope of the `__init__` function you will loose access to the `a`.

Comment: So `a` is akin to a class attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that `__init__` isn't a constructor in the sense of other languages, like C++. It's really just a function that runs on an object after the "bare" object is created. B's `__init__` function is conventionally responsible for calling A's `__init__`, but it doesn't have to - if `A.__init__` never gets called, then then A's attribute `a` doesn't get added to the object, and so you get an error when you try to access it.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this problem, you'll need to use

```
class B(A):
    def __init__(self, b, a):
        super(A, self).__init__(a)
```

Make sure you declare the classes as new style objects, something you're already doing

[edit: clarification]

Comment: You mean't `super(B, self).__init__(a)` I guess :)